# Logstash Http input plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, elk

I am looking to implement an HTTP listener to ingest JSON over a specific port on an AWS EC2 instance. Currently I have Elasticsearch, Logstash, and Kibana running on the same cluster and I have validated that they're all working in conjunction with one-another. When I attempt to open a port (5602) for the logstash-http-input plugin, I am unable to hit it whatsoever. 
This is my .conf file (located in /etc/logstash/conf.d)

```
input {
  http {
    port => 5602
    host => "0.0.0.0"
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "%{[@metadata][http]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

I'm unfamiliar with the ELK stack in general, so anything would help!

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you are using is for incoming http traffic, logstash acts as a http server. You need something what will issue http requests to the outer worlds and here is a http-poller-plugin you should have a look on: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-http_poller.htmland a blogpost for the very same plugin: https://www.elastic.co/de/blog/introducing-logstash-http-poller

If you need sth more like a crawler, have a look on apache nutch: https://nutch.apache.org/

Comment: I don't think I explained my problem well enough. I'm not looking for a crawler or poller, but instead I need a restful endpoint continuously exposed so I can input log data from http post requests.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it has more to do with AWS policy on ports than with Logstash itself: I'm pretty used to working with the https input plugin, and in Docker environments it has no problem on tapping into whatever port you tell it - just as you did.

Does your EC2 instance have any firewall, or does AWS have any means of manually opening up ports? If so, check for port 5602; most probably it is closed on the 0.0.0.0 interface.

Another way of checking whether Logstash is working properly or not is to turn on the pipeline and use some other local service to send some data to the port 5602 on localhost; most probably the port is opened on that interface.